# Can't display text input value to python canvas

Tags: python, canvas

Hello I'm new to python programming.i try to create simple GUI using python simleguitk.I create a text-box and button in my canvas and i need to display text on canvas that is text-box input text when button click.

this my code

```
 import simpleguitk

msg="hello"
color="white"

def draw(canvas):
    canvas.draw_text(msg,[100,100],24,color)

def btnclick():
    global msg
    msg=txt.get_text()

def txtInput(text):
    pass


frame=simpleguitk.create_frame("Test",300,200)
txt=frame.add_input("txt",txtInput,50)
btn=frame.add_button("click",btnclick)

frame.set_draw_handler(draw)

frame.start()
```

but when i run the code I got this error
[image]

how can i fix this error ? need quick help.

Comment: The add_input() returns an Input object. Are you sure that it has a get_text() method since that is where the error is? Is there not another way to get the text?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
def txtInput(text):
   pass
```

With

```
def txtInput(text):
    global msg
    msg = str(text)
    return msg
```

Comment: Use the `{}` button or press `Ctrl+K` or type four spaces to format code snippets.